# Unable to return serializer class in Django reset framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am developing a Web API using the Django REST framework. I am new to Django and Python. The problem I am having now is that I cannot return the serializer class.

This is my project structure

[image]

I created quickstart/serializers.py with the following definition

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from rest_framework import serializers


class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'username', 'email', 'groups')


class GroupSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ('url', 'name')
```

This is my quickstart/views.py definition

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from rest_framework import viewsets
from quickstart.serializers import UserSerializer, GroupSerializer


class UserViewSet (viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all().order_by('-date_joined')
    serializer_class = UserSerializer


class GroupViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Group.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GroupSerializer
```

This is the definition of quickstart/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from quickstart import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('users/', views.UserViewSet)
]
```

This is the urls.py inside the secondly red-lined folder

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from quickstart import views
from rest_framework import routers


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('quickstart.urls'))
]
```

When I access to this url (http://127.0.0.1:9191/users/) in the browser, I get this error.

```
TypeError at /users/
__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:9191/users/
Django Version: 2.1.2
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
Exception Location: C:\Users\Acer\PycharmProjects\MementoDjango\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response, line 124
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Acer\PycharmProjects\MementoDjango\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.6.5
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\Acer\\PycharmProjects\\MementoDjango',
 'C:\\Users\\Acer\\PycharmProjects\\MementoDjango\\venv\\Scripts\\python36.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Acer\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Acer\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Acer\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32',
 'C:\\Users\\Acer\\PycharmProjects\\MementoDjango\\venv',
 'C:\\Users\\Acer\\PycharmProjects\\MementoDjango\\venv\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\Acer\\PycharmProjects\\MementoDjango\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-39.1.0-py3.6.egg',
 'C:\\Users\\Acer\\PycharmProjects\\MementoDjango\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\pip-10.0.1-py3.6.egg']
Server time:    Sat, 13 Oct 2018 20:33:23 +0000
```

[image]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't have anything to do with "returning a serializer class".

The problem is in your urls.py; this isn't at all how you use a ViewSet there. You need to use it with a Router: see [the documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/), which has exactly your use case:

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet, basename='user')
urlpatterns = router.urls
```